# Can you identify this kind of pipe?

Tags: plumbing

I have a drain pipe for a shower. I need to attach a new pvc drain to it for a kerdi shower base. How can I tell if this is cast iron or galvanized, or something else? I'm assuming I will need to cut off that flange on top prior to doing anything.

[image: unidentified pipe]

For the record, house was built in 1956 in Hampton, Virginia. Main stack is cast iron, also lots of galvanized for other drains.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe is cast iron . The collar/flange is likely brass.

Answer (score 1):

Agree it's cast iron, but the collar looks like galv steel. Hit it with a cold chisel and hammer.